# TypeError: not a valid non-string sequence or mapping object

Tags: python, http, post, eloqua

TypeError: not a valid non-string sequence or mapping object
•   Constructed the data dictionary and used json.dumps
•   Post request along with the data

```
data = {
    "filter": "'{{Activity.Type}}'='Bounceback'",
    "name": "Bulk Activity Export - Bounceback",
    "fields": {
        "ActivityId": "{{Activity.Id}}"
   }
}

data = json.dumps(data)

print(request.post("/activities/exports", data = data ))
```

The post request method (this is not complete code, just the part which does the post request)

```
def post(self, url, data):
    return self.request('POST', url, data)

print(request)
if data != None:
   data = urllib.urlencode(data)
```

The results:

There is no issues with the authentication. Here is the request object and http headers. I get TypeError: not a valid non-string sequence or mapping object error.

```
data object: {"filter": "'{{Activity.Type}}'='Bounceback'", "fields": {"AssetType": "{{Activity.Asset.Type}}", "ActivityId": "{{Activity.Id}}", "EmailAddress": "{{Activity.Field(EmailAddress)}}", "AssetId": "{{Activity.Asset.Id}}", "ActivityDate": "{{Activity.CreatedAt}}", "AssetName": "{{Activity.Asset.Name}}", "CampaignId": "{{Activity.Campaign.Id}}", "ExternalId": "{{Activity.ExternalId}}", "ActivityType": "{{Activity.Type}}"}, "name": "Bulk Activity Export - Bounceback"}
```

Header:

```
{'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Basic RmlhdE1hcmtldGluZ1xGMzIwMDJCOkFjY2V'}
```